# How to make a Drupal theme with PhpStorm

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, phpstorm, drupal-theming

I want to make my own custom theme with PhpStorm.

I found lots of information how to create your own module, but nothing for theme with this IDE. For creating a module you should open a PhpStorm, to choose from "Project Type" -> "Drupal Module", to add some additional settings and project is created for development.

So, is there the same feature for creating a "Drupal Theme"? For instance, "Project Type" -> "Drupal Theme".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal theme is just bunch of files and it's not important what editor/environment you use to create it. There are a lot of tutorials on the net explaining how to make a theme.

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/12/27/how-to-create-a-drupal-7-theme-from-scratch/

Google for some more and you'll find them.